# How to wait for a click() event to load in phantomjs before continuing?

Tags: click, phantomjs, pageload

Phantomjs has these two really handy callbacks `onLoadStarted` and `onLoadFinished` which allow you to essentially pause execution while the page is loading.  But I've been searching and I can't find an equivalent for if you `click()` a submit button or hyperlink.  A similar page load happens but `onLoadStarted` doesn't get called for this event I guess because there isn't an explicit `page.open()` that happens.  I'm trying to figure out a clean way to suspend execution while this load takes place.

One solution is obviously nested setTimeout's but I'd like to avoid this scenario because it's hacky and relies on trial and error instead of something reliable and more robust like testing against something or waiting for an event.

Is there a specific callback for this kind of page load that I missed?  Or maybe there's some kind of generic code pattern that can deal with this sort of thing?

EDIT:

I still haven't figured out how to get it to pause.  Here's the code that doesn't call the `onLoadStarted()` function when I call the `click()` command:

```
var loadInProgress = false;

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

page.open(loginPage.url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
        fs.write(filePath + errorState, 1, 'w');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function (loginPage, credentials) {
            console.log('inside loginPage evaluate function...\n')
            document.querySelector('input[id=' + loginPage.userId + ']').value = credentials.username;
            document.querySelector('input[id=' + loginPage.passId + ']').value = credentials.password;      
            document.querySelector('input[id=' + loginPage.submitId + ']').click();
            //var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
            //aTags[1].click();
        }, loginPage, credentials);

        page.render(renderPath + 'postLogin.png');
        console.log('rendered post-login');
```

I double checked that the id is correct.  The `page.render()` will show that the information is submitted, but only if I put it in a setTimeout(), otherwise it renders it immediately and I only see the credentials inputted, before the page redirect.  Maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: You haven't shown how you set `onLoadStarted` and `onLoadFinished`. You have to do it before the `evaluate` and the finished handler should contain the `render`

Comment: I edited it to include the callback definitions.  I don't think this is the problem though because they're not getting called for the `click()` event to begin with.  They do get called for each `page.open()` though.

Comment: Maybe you `exit` too early. Please see the last snippet in my answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: I think I know what the cause is now... the page I'm logging into is an asp.net page, and if I'm not mistaken, aspx pages do not actually return a new html url, but instead dynamically change the html tags and data on the same page... I'll have to confirm this.  The only doubt I have is that the url actually does change when I hit the submit button.  It's still a .aspx page but it's a different url.  Again, I don't know too much about .aspx so I'll have to test some things out.

Answer (score 13):

I think the `onLoadStarted` and `onLoadFinished` functions are everything you need. Take for example the following script:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    if (response.stage !== "end") return;
    console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + response.url);
};
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
    console.log('Request (#' + requestData.id + '): ' + requestData.url);
};
page.onUrlChanged = function(targetUrl) {
    console.log('New URL: ' + targetUrl);
};
page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    console.log('Load Finished: ' + status);
};
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    console.log('Load Started');
};
page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
    console.log('Trying to navigate to: ' + url);
};

page.open("http://example.com", function(status){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        // click
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        document.querySelector("a").dispatchEvent(e);
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);
});
```

It prints

```
Trying to navigate to: http://example.com/
Request (#1): http://example.com/
Load Started
New URL: http://example.com/
Response (#1, stage "end"): http://example.com/
Load Finished: success
Trying to navigate to: http://www.iana.org/domains/example
Request (#2): http://www.iana.org/domains/example
Load Started
Trying to navigate to: http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved
Request (#3): http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved
Response (#2, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/domains/example
New URL: http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved
Request (#4): http://www.iana.org/_css/2013.1/screen.css
Request (#5): http://www.iana.org/_js/2013.1/jquery.js
Request (#6): http://www.iana.org/_js/2013.1/iana.js
Response (#3, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved
Response (#6, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/_js/2013.1/iana.js
Response (#4, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/_css/2013.1/screen.css
Response (#5, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/_js/2013.1/jquery.js
Request (#7): http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/iana-logo-header.svg
Request (#8): http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/icann-logo.svg
Response (#8, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/icann-logo.svg
Response (#7, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/iana-logo-header.svg
Request (#9): http://www.iana.org/_css/2013.1/print.css
Response (#9, stage "end"): http://www.iana.org/_css/2013.1/print.css
Load Finished: success
```

It shows that clicking a link emits the LoadStarted event once and NavigationRequested event twice, because there is a redirect. The trick is to add the event handlers before doing the action:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("http://example.com", function(status){
    page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
        console.log('Load Finished: ' + status);
        page.render("test37_next_page.png");
        phantom.exit();
    };
    page.onLoadStarted = function() {
        console.log('Load Started');
    };

    page.evaluate(function(){
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        document.querySelector("a").dispatchEvent(e);
    });
});
```

If you need to do those things, maybe it is time to try something else like [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/). It runs on top of PhantomJS, but has a much better API for navigating web pages.

Answer (score 8):

Use the high-level wrapper, [nightmarejs](http://www.nightmarejs.org/).
You can easily `click` there and wait afterwards.

Here is the code (Examples section):

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
new Nightmare()
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
    .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
    .click('.searchsubmit')
    .run(function (err, nightmare) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('Done!');
    });
```

More examples and API usage can be found at [github](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api)

Comment: nightmarejs is a node module and therefore not applicable for plain PhantomJS.

Comment: using the library makes it much simpler though. Thanks for pointing it out! for my needs it was a better option

Comment: Wow, hours of struggling with phantom, all my problems solved in 5 minutes with nightmare. What an amazing tool, can't +1 it enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code based on some other answers. In my case, I didn't need to specifically evaluate any other javascript. I just needed to wait for the page to finish loading.

```
var system = require('system');
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Try to pass some arguments when invoking this script!');
}
else {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    var address = system.args[1];

    page.open(address, function(status){
        page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        };    
    });     
}
```

Save the above in a file called "scrape.js" and call it this way:

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true scrape.js https://www.example.com
```

The SSL-related params are added to avoid other issues that I was having with certain HTTPS sites (related to certificate loading issues).

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Are you sure this code works as you describe it? The `page.open` callback function should actually be called at the same time as the `page.onLoadFinished` event handler firing. Doing both things would mean to me that the second is not fired.

Comment: @Artjom-B Yes it works. It's the same thing that you posted except that I removed the  page.onLoadStarted and page.evaluate calls since I didn't need them. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.