# Waiting for the click event in PhantomJS 2 with Jasmine 2.x and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I am trying to test an Angular directive that uses the click event and getting nowhere. I can get the event to fire just fine, but PhantomJS2 just takes forever to make the event happen and I can't figure out a way to get Jasmine to wait for it to happen before running the assertion. I've searched quite a bit and the most common response is this: [How to wait for a click() event to load in phantomjs before continuing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270852/how-to-wait-for-a-click-event-to-load-in-phantomjs-before-continuing). Sadly, that guy hasn't figured it out either, and I'm not waiting for a page to load, just for the click event to finally register. I'm hoping that someone else has and just didn't see that question or didn't want to start a reply on such an old question. For reference, the directive in question selects the text within an input tag if there is none already selected. I've tried every permutation of timeouts that I can think of, but nothing works. The last attempt involved using the `done()` function from Jasmine, but still no luck.

```
//the default value in the input is "unchanged"
it('should not select anything if there is already a selection in the element', function(done) {
    element[0].setSelectionRange(2, element[0].value.length);
    element.triggerHandler('click');
    scope.$digest();
    expect(theWindow.getSelection().toString()).toEqual('changed');
    done();
});
```

All reasonable suggestions will be considered. I'd be ecstatic if someone had a link to a solution that I somehow didn't find with my Google-foo.

Note: I got the idea about using setTimeout from here: https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/how-to-click-on-a-div-or-span-using-phantomjs/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using jasmine's runs and waitFor function necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619664/why-is-using-jasmines-runs-and-waitfor-function-necessary)

Comment: It might take me a bit to get back to this code, but I will definitely check it out and see if that solves the problem.